# Own command to create new environment

Tags: macros, environments, theorems

The following code isn't very minimal but I hope you will be able to understand the code.

```
\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{999}
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum,ntheorem}
\usepackage[ntheorem]{mdframed}
\makeatletter
%\newtheorem{<envname>}[<numberedlike>]{<caption>}[<within>]
%\newmdtheoremenv[<mdframed-options>]{<envname>}[<numberedlike>]{<caption>}[<within>]
%\md@tempa[<mdframed-options>]
%\md@tempb{<envname>}%
%\md@tempc[<numberedlike>]%
%\md@tempd{<caption>}%
%\md@tempe[<within>]%
\newrobustcmd*\newmdtheoremenv{%
   \kernel@ifnextchar[%]
     {\newmdtheoremenv@i}{\newmdtheoremenv@i[]}%
}
\newrobustcmd*\newmdtheoremenv@i[2][]{%
\def\md@tempa{#1}%
\def\md@tempb{#2}%
    \kernel@ifnextchar[%]
     {\newmdtheoremenv@ii}{\newmdtheoremenv@ii[]}%
}

%\newmdtheoremenv@ii[<mdframed-options>]{<envname>}[<numberedlike>]{<caption>}
\newrobustcmd*\newmdtheoremenv@ii[2][]{%
\def\md@tempc{#1}%
\def\md@tempd{#2}%
    \kernel@ifnextchar[%]
     {\newmdtheoremenv@iii}{\newmdtheoremenv@iii[]}%
}

%\newmdtheoremenv@ii[<mdframed-options>]{<envname>}[<numberedlike>]{<caption>}[<within>]
\newrobustcmd*\newmdtheoremenv@iii[1][]{%
   \def\md@tempe{#1}%
   \ifboolexpr{ not (test {\ifdefempty{\md@tempc}})
              and 
             not (test {\ifdefempty{\md@tempe}})
           }{%
             \md@PackageWarning{You defined {\string\newtheorem} with ^^J
                                both optional arguments^^J 
                                <numeredlike> and <within>. This isn't allowed^^J
                                \mdframedpackagename will use <numeredlike>\MessageBreak}%
             \newtheorem{\csname md\md@tempb \endcsname}[\md@tempc]{\md@tempd}%
            }%
            {\ifdefempty{\md@tempc}{}{\newtheorem{md\md@tempb}[\md@tempc]{\md@tempd}}%
             \ifdefempty{\md@tempe}{}{\newtheorem{md\md@tempb}{\md@tempd}[\md@tempe]}%
            }%
   \ifboolexpr{test {\ifdefempty{\md@tempc}}
                and 
               test {\ifdefempty{\md@tempe}}
               }{%
               \newtheorem{md\md@tempb}{\md@tempd}%
               }{}%
\expandafter\global\expandafter\@namedef\expandafter{\md@tempb}{%
   \expandafter\mdfsetup\expandafter{\md@tempa}%
               \begin{mdframed}[]\begin{md\md@tempb}%
    }%
\expandafter\global\expandafter\@namedef\expandafter{end\md@tempb}{%
              \end{md\md@tempb}\end{mdframed}%
   }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
{\small\verb+\newmdtheoremenv[mdframed-options]{envname}[numberedlike]{caption}[within]+}
\newmdtheoremenv[linecolor=blue,backgroundcolor=red]{beispiel}{Beispiel}
%\newmdtheoremenv[linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=yellow]{spiel}{Spiel}
\begin{beispiel}[Antwort]
Test
\end{beispiel}

\vspace*{2em}

%\hallo

\vspace*{2em}

%\begin{spiel}%[Antwort]
%Test
%\end{spiel}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to create the command `\newmdtheoremenv`. In the minimal example it works well as long as only one `\newmdtheoremenv` is used. 
When I use the second `\newmdtheoremenv` the first will be overwritten. How can I avoid this and how can I modify the example so that the command `\newmdtheoremenv` can be used multiple times.

Comment: On a general note: Only the first macro at the user level need to be robust. Also you check for `[` manually but then use macros which already has an optional arguments and repeat the exact same by themselves! So change `\newrobustcmd*\newmdtheoremenv@i[2][]` with a simple `\def\newmdtheoremenv@[#1]#2` or remove the `\kernel@ifnextchar[` code. Only one is required; both together don't make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Martin's answer doesn't work, because the macros `\md@tempa` and similar are not expanded at definition time and so all theorems will have the same label as the last defined one.

```
\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{999}
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum,ntheorem}
\usepackage[ntheorem]{mdframed}
\makeatletter
%\newtheorem{<envname>}[<numberedlike>]{<caption>}[<within>]
%\newmdtheoremenv[<mdframed-options>]{<envname>}[<numberedlike>]{<caption>}[<within>]
%\md@tempa[<mdframed-options>]
%\md@tempb{<envname>}%
%\md@tempc[<numberedlike>]%
%\md@tempd{<caption>}%
%\md@tempe[<within>]%
\renewrobustcmd*\newmdtheoremenv{%
   \kernel@ifnextchar[%]
     {\newmdtheoremenv@i}{\newmdtheoremenv@i[]}%
}
\def\newmdtheoremenv@i[#1]#2{%
    \def\md@tempa{#1}%
    \def\md@tempb{#2}%
    \kernel@ifnextchar[%]
     {\newmdtheoremenv@ii}{\newmdtheoremenv@ii[]}%
}

\def\newmdtheoremenv@ii[#1]#2{%
    \def\md@tempc{#1}%
    \def\md@tempd{#2}%
    \kernel@ifnextchar[%]
     {\newmdtheoremenv@iii}{\newmdtheoremenv@iii[]}%
}

\def\newmdtheoremenv@iii[#1]{%
   \def\md@tempe{#1}%
   \ifboolexpr{ not (test {\ifdefempty{\md@tempc}})
              and 
             not (test {\ifdefempty{\md@tempe}})
           }{%
             \md@PackageWarning{You defined {\string\newtheorem} with ^^J
                                both optional arguments^^J 
                                <numberedlike> and <within>. This isn't allowed^^J
                                \mdframedpackagename will use <numeredlike>\MessageBreak}%
             \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
               \noexpand\newtheorem{\csname md\md@tempb\endcsname}[\md@tempc]{\md@tempd}}\x
            }%

            {\ifdefempty{\md@tempc}{}{
               \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
                 \noexpand\newtheorem{md\md@tempb}[\md@tempc]{\md@tempd}}\x
}%
             \ifdefempty{\md@tempe}{}{
               \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
                 \noexpand\newtheorem{md\md@tempb}{\md@tempd}[\md@tempe]}\x
}%
            }%
   \ifboolexpr{test {\ifdefempty{\md@tempc}}
                and 
               test {\ifdefempty{\md@tempe}}
               }{%
                 \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
                   \noexpand\newtheorem{md\md@tempb}{\md@tempd}}\x
               }{}%
   \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname\md@tempb\endcsname{\noexpand\mdfsetup{\md@tempa}%
               \noexpand\begin{mdframed}[]\noexpand\begin{md\md@tempb}%
    }%
   \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname end\md@tempb\endcsname{%
              \noexpand\end{md\md@tempb}\noexpand\end{mdframed}%
   }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
{\small\verb+\newmdtheoremenv[mdframed-options]{envname}[numberedlike]{caption}[within]+}
\newmdtheoremenv[linecolor=blue,backgroundcolor=red]{beispiel}[section]{Beispiel}
\newmdtheoremenv[linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=yellow]{spiel}[subsection]{Spiel}

\begin{beispiel}[Antwort]
Test
\end{beispiel}

\vspace*{2em}

\begin{spiel}%[Antwort]
Test
\end{spiel}
\end{document}
```

### NOTE

I've used `\renewrobustcmd` because the mechanism has already been included in my version of **mdframed**.

Answer (score 4):

You currently define the environments so that they use the temporary macros which are getting overwritten at every new declaration. You need to properly expand them first. Also you don't need to expand the argument of `\@namedef` because it is anyway expanded by the underlying `\csname .. \endcsname`.

```
\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{999}
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum,ntheorem}
\usepackage[ntheorem]{mdframed}
\makeatletter
%\newtheorem{<envname>}[<numberedlike>]{<caption>}[<within>]
%\newmdtheoremenv[<mdframed-options>]{<envname>}[<numberedlike>]{<caption>}[<within>]
%\md@tempa[<mdframed-options>]
%\md@tempb{<envname>}%
%\md@tempc[<numberedlike>]%
%\md@tempd{<caption>}%
%\md@tempe[<within>]%
\newrobustcmd*\newmdtheoremenv{%
   \kernel@ifnextchar[%]
     {\newmdtheoremenv@i}{\newmdtheoremenv@i[]}%
}
\def\newmdtheoremenv@i[#1]#2{%
    \def\md@tempa{#1}%
    \def\md@tempb{#2}%
    \kernel@ifnextchar[%]
     {\newmdtheoremenv@ii}{\newmdtheoremenv@ii[]}%
}

\def\newmdtheoremenv@ii[#1]#2{%
    \def\md@tempc{#1}%
    \def\md@tempd{#2}%
    \kernel@ifnextchar[%]
     {\newmdtheoremenv@iii}{\newmdtheoremenv@iii[]}%
}

\def\newmdtheoremenv@iii[#1]{%
   \def\md@tempe{#1}%
   \ifboolexpr{ not (test {\ifdefempty{\md@tempc}})
              and 
             not (test {\ifdefempty{\md@tempe}})
           }{%
             \md@PackageWarning{You defined {\string\newtheorem} with ^^J
                                both optional arguments^^J 
                                <numeredlike> and <within>. This isn't allowed^^J
                                \mdframedpackagename will use <numeredlike>\MessageBreak}%
             \newtheorem{\csname md\md@tempb \endcsname}[\md@tempc]{\md@tempd}%
            }%
            {\ifdefempty{\md@tempc}{}{\newtheorem{md\md@tempb}[\md@tempc]{\md@tempd}}%
             \ifdefempty{\md@tempe}{}{\newtheorem{md\md@tempb}{\md@tempd}[\md@tempe]}%
            }%
   \ifboolexpr{test {\ifdefempty{\md@tempc}}
                and 
               test {\ifdefempty{\md@tempe}}
               }{%
               \newtheorem{md\md@tempb}{\md@tempd}%
               }{}%
   \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname\md@tempb\endcsname{\noexpand\mdfsetup{\md@tempa}%
               \noexpand\begin{mdframed}[]\noexpand\begin{md\md@tempb}%
    }%
   \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname end\md@tempb\endcsname{%
              \noexpand\end{md\md@tempb}\noexpand\end{mdframed}%
   }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
{\small\verb+\newmdtheoremenv[mdframed-options]{envname}[numberedlike]{caption}[within]+}
\newmdtheoremenv[linecolor=blue,backgroundcolor=red]{beispiel}{Beispiel}
\newmdtheoremenv[linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=yellow]{spiel}{Spiel}

\begin{beispiel}[Antwort]
Test
\end{beispiel}

\vspace*{2em}

\begin{spiel}%[Antwort]
Test
\end{spiel}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will use also the important information in the comment above.