# Defining the caption of newtheorem with a command

Tags: tex-core, environments, theorems

In the example below you can see that both environments get the same caption.

How to prevent this? You will get the same result if you use an other package like `amsthm`, `theorem` or `thmtools`.

```
\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{999}
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ntheorem,xcolor}
\def\tempA{Game}
\newtheorem{game}{\color{red}\bfseries\tempA}
\def\tempA{Example}
\newtheorem{example}{\color{blue}\bfseries\tempA}
\begin{document}

\begin{example}
Test
\end{example}

\vspace*{2em}

\begin{game}
Test
\end{game}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Own command to create new environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26298/own-command-to-create-new-environment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course: the second `\def` overrides the meaning of the first one: `\tempA` is expanded only when `\begin{game}` and `\begin{example}` are *used*, not when defined. At that time, `\tempA` expands to `Example`.

```
\def\tempA{Game}
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \noexpand\newtheorem{game}{\noexpand\color{red}\noexpand\bfseries\tempA}}
\x
\def\tempA{Example}
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \noexpand\newtheorem{example}{\noexpand\color{red}\noexpand\bfseries\tempA}}
\x
```

will do, but it's rather cumbersome

Comment: +1 -- Works well. Maybe somebody knows a solution which isn't cumbersome ;-)

Comment: Please, be more specific about your problem; in the shown form it's quite easy: write `Game` and `Example` instead of `\tempA` in the definitions.

Comment: Yes that is true ;-) -- The problem base on this question: [Own command to create new environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26298/own-command-to-create-new-environment). I used this answer for my package but this simple question demonstrate my bug.

Comment: I've added another answer to that question